# How to initialize Map from List in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Using `Map.empty` and `Map.add` is verbose, is there something like:

```ml
Map.of_list [(1,"A"); (2,"B"); (3,"C")];;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if the following are *the best* ways of doing it, but it might be helpful nevertheless:

You can use [`List.to_seq`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALto_seq)
and [`Map.of_seq`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html#VALof_seq):

```ml
module M = Map.Make (Int)

let m = [(1,"A"); (2,"B"); (3,"C")] |> List.to_seq |> M.of_seq
```

With reducing it could be something like this:

```ml
let m = List.fold_left (fun m (k,v) -> M.add k v m) M.empty [(1,"A"); (2,"B"); (3,"C")]
```

The library [containers](https://github.com/c-cube/ocaml-containers) offers [`of_list`](https://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-containers/3.4/containers/CCMap/module-type-S/index.html#val-of_list) as well:

```ml
(* either open Containers to replace modules *)
open Containers
module M = Map.Make (Int)
(* or use the extended module explicitly *)
module M = CCMap.Make (Int)

let m = M.of_list [(1,"A"); (2,"B"); (3,"C")]
```

Comment: I am a total OCaml noob and this seems exactly what I was looking for (specifically the first part - Map from List). Why do you say it is maybe not the best way?  Is this not idiomatic, or is bad in some other way?

Comment: I said that because I'm not an OCaml-expert either.
The first approach uses an intermediate representation using the Seq. It wraps a function into a variant, and makes it possible to iterate some structure externally. However, that makes it slightly slower than the second approach (by ~2%).
Both approaches are tail-recursive, and the `of_seq` also adds elements one-by-one using a fold.
The standard-library-extension `containers` does it the same way as approach #2: https://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-containers/3.4/containers/CCMap/module-type-S/index.html#val-of_list

Answer (score 3):

Since OCaml 5.1 (released on 2023-09-14) there is [Map.of_list](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.S.html#VALof_list)

```ml
module MapWithIntegerKeys = Map.Make (Int);;
let map = MapWithIntegerKeys.of_list [(1, "A"); (2, "B"); (3, "C")];;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Base](https://opensource.janestreet.com/base/), Base's Map module exposes [`Map.of_alist`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Map/index.html#val-of_alist):

```
Map.of_alist (module Int) [(1, "A"); (2, "B"); (3, "C")];;
```

If you are sure your list contains no duplicates, you can call [`Map.of_alist_exn`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Map/index.html#val-of_alist_exn).